# How to create a multi-step Enumerator library in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to make an Enumeration library to use with some of my python scripts. 
It would be used like so:

*Enum.py*

```
class Pictures():
    Turtle='imgur url here'

class Names():
    NameOne = 'jim'
    NameTwo = 'greg'
```

*MyScript.py*

```
import Enum

print(Enum.Names.NameOne,' is a name!')
```

I've seen about using classes from the python library, but i can't figure out how to make it 'multi stepped'.

Comment: Have you tried the code you have so far? Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.

Comment: Oh. It works all of a sudden. Beforehand, it was throwing an objectnotfound exception.

Comment: FYI `Enum` is the name of a class in the standard library that does something similar, so try naming your class something else.